# Trying to get property of non-object - con codigo QR

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Hola a todos estoy creando un pdf y dentro del pdf estoy colocando un codigo qr con los datos de N persona pero tengo un error a la hora de setear los valores a mi código QR me sale este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando imrpimo mi sentencia sql aparece esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por ultimo esto esta en mi controlador :

```
 public function print_qr() {
    $res = $this->input->get('numero');
    $nombre = $this->input->get('name');
    $archivo = $this->resolucion->extraer_datos_qr($res, $nombre);

    $qr_code_config = array();
    $qr_code_config['cacheable'] = $this->config->item('cacheable');
    $qr_code_config['cachedir'] = $this->config->item('cachedir');
    $qr_code_config['imagedir'] = $this->config->item('imagedir');
    $qr_code_config['errorlog'] = $this->config->item('errorlog');
    $qr_code_config['ciqrcodelib'] = $this->config->item('ciqrcodelib');
    $qr_code_config['quality'] = $this->config->item('quality');
    $qr_code_config['size'] = $this->config->item('size');
    $qr_code_config['black'] = $this->config->item('black');
    $qr_code_config['white'] = $this->config->item('white');
    $this->ci_qr_code->initialize($qr_code_config);

    $image_name = 'codigoQR' . ".png";

    $codeContents = "Nombre y Apellidos:";
    $codeContents .= "\n";
    $codeContents .= $archivo->NOMBRES_COMPLETOS;
    $params['data'] = $codeContents;
    $params['level'] = 'H';
    $params['size'] = 2;
    $params['savename'] = FCPATH . $qr_code_config['imagedir'] . $image_name;
    $this->ci_qr_code->generate($params);
    $this->data['qr_code_image_url'] = base_url() . $qr_code_config['imagedir'] . $image_name;
    $file = $params['savename'];
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Cual es la linea 147 que menciona el error?

Comment: $codeContents .= $archivo->NOMBRES_COMPLETOS;

Comment: **A.** ¿Seguro que el objeto que obtienes aquí: `$archivo = $this->resolucion->extraer_datos_qr($res, $nombre);` es devuelto correctamente? **B.** ¿Seguro que el objeto `$archivo` posee una propiedad llamada `NOMBRES_COMPLETOS`. De acuerdo al mensaje de error, algo está fallando en **A**, verifica por tanto esta llamada: `$this->resolucion->extraer_datos_qr($res, $nombre);`

Comment: En la segunda imagen despejo tus dudas